# Like operator on input parameters in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've just begun to add writing stored procedures to my SQL repertoire and I'm sure this is a noob question.  Can someone point me in the right direction about how to use the `like` operator instead of the `=` operator in this scenario?  The object of this is to find the first 3 common numbers out of a potential 5 digit number

stored procedure:

```
create proc dbo.MultipleDrugs (@condition varchar(50))
as
SELECT  *, 100.0 * round(SUM(numwithanxiety) OVER (partition BY sex) / cast(TotalSexCounts AS float), 4) overAllPercentByGender
FROM (SELECT x.sex, injurylevel, SUM(sexandlevelcounts) OVER (partition BY x.sex) numByInjury, sum(sexandlevelcounts) AS numWithAnxiety, 
      100.0 * round(cast(sexandlevelcounts AS float) / SUM(sexandlevelcounts) OVER (partition BY x.sex), 4) AS percentWith, y.TotalSexCounts
      FROM (SELECT sex, injurylevel, COUNT(*) AS sexAndLevelCounts
             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT m.patid, m.sex, m.injurylevel
              FROM  members AS m INNER JOIN
               icdClm AS ic ON ic.patid = m.PATID
               --*****when I leave this operator as like and use
               --*****equals in the exec statement it works
               WHERE ic.icd LIKE @condition) t
              GROUP BY sex, injurylevel) x INNER JOIN
              (SELECT m.sex, COUNT(DISTINCT patid) TotalSexCounts
                FROM members m
                GROUP BY m.sex) y ON y.sex = x.sex
               GROUP BY x.sex, x.injuryLevel, x.sexAndLevelCounts, y.TotalSexCounts) rr
 go
```

This runs, but I cannot use the `like` operator

```
exec dbo.MultipleDrugs  N'70700'
```

This is what I'd like to do

```
exec dbo.MultipleDrugs  like '707%'
```

Comment: have you tried doing: LIKE '%' + @condition + '%' in your sp?

Comment: you don't need the like in your exex call, just in your query

Comment: And then leave "like" out of your exec syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec dbo.MultipleDrugs N'707%'
```

Comment: deceptively easy, and of course the only thing that I didn't try.  Thanks!  I didn't think that using the wildcard operator would work here with using `like` in the exec statement, but that shows what I know

Comment: Are you going to be calling this by code? if you are remember to add the "%" to the beginning / end of your string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide the `LIKE` operator in your exec call - you've already got `like` in  your SPROC. Consider instead a simpler case:

```
create proc FindObjects @Name NVARCHAR(50)
as
    select * 
        from sys.objects
        where name like @Name
```

And then calling this:

```
exec FindObjects 'sys%'
```

returns

```
sysrscols
sysrowsets
sysallocunits
sysfiles1
syspriorities
sysfgfrag
```

etc.

Comment: very good, very usable answer without having to create a bunch of tables.  +1

Comment: I was just being lazy :). Of course, you know that your SPROC has sex and drugs ... just missing RnR!

Comment: you win one internet.  don't spend it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Change your SP so that the following occurs:

```
LIKE '%' + @condition + '%'
```

Comment: when I run that the error I get is `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.`

Comment: so it is failing here(?):   WHERE ic.icd LIKE '%' + @condition + '%'

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use like this in the procedure .
set @SearchString='%'+ @SearchString + '%'